# Enable to over-ride django-allauth UserSignupView

Tags: python, django, web-services, python-2.7, django-allauth

My reason for writing a custom signup view is to override the form_valid() of django- allauth SignupView and do as above.

For some reason the control is not coming inside CustomSignupView when i click on signup button, instead it is going to the allauth UserSignup view's form_valid() and executing that.
Please help me how to access CustomSignUpView.
This is my implementation

views.py:

```
from allauth.account.views import LoginView, SignupView

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

from .forms import CustomLoginForm

from .notify import Notification

class CustomSignupView(SignupView):

    notify = Notification()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(CustomSignupView, self).__init__(*kwargs)
        self.form_class = SignupForm

    def send_email(self, form): # custom implementation
        self.notify.notify(self.entity_type, form.cleaned_data)


    def form_valid(self, form):

        self.send_email(form)
        return super(CustomSignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is django's implementation:

```
class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
             FormView):
    template_name = "account/signup.html"
    form_class = SignupForm
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    success_url = None

def get_success_url(self):
    # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
    ret = (get_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                 self.redirect_field_name)
           or self.success_url)
    return ret

def form_valid(self, form):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    user = form.save(self.request)
    return complete_signup(self.request, user,
                           app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                           self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See i just want to send email notification to the admin on form_valid saying that a new user has signed up for our website.
By over-riding allauth views.

Comment: Yes, but what is your question? Are you having a problem?

Comment: I have edited the question with proper error and formatting. Did you get the question?

Comment: More or less, you should have the specific error that you are getting in the body, not as the title. The title should be some sort of summary like "Getting Method Resolution Order error when trying to create django class based view".

Comment: I have found the desired solution for the problem. My urls were not defined properly. Thanks for all the help people.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using class based views, so you should probably implement a form_valid method:

```
class CustomSignupView(SignupView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupView, self).__init__(*kwargs)
        self.form_class = CustomSignupForm

    def send_email(self, form): # custom implementation
        self.notify.notify(self.entity_type, form.cleaned_data)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        #show some error etc
        pass

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.send_email(form)
        return super(CustomSignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

don't know if this is what You try to achieve

Comment: I have found the desired solution for the problem. My urls were not defined properly. Thanks for all the help people.